# Trouble Packaging and signing an ios app on Visual Studio Cordova

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I am following the instructions from microsoft on this

https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/tree/master/tutorial-package-publish#ios

But got stuck at " add it to the Code signing section of Build Settings for Xcode. "

Where can I find my cordova project in mac as this screenshot?

https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/blob/master/tutorial-package-publish/media/ios-xcodeBuildSettings.png

Answer (score 0):

You should go to the project directory->platforms->iOS and find projectName.xcodeproj . You should open it, Xcode with your project will be opened.